# Print the elements in the tree that start with a vowel in reverse alphabetic order

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree, binary-search

In the  given Binary search program I have to print the elements in the tree that start with a vowel in reverse alphabetic order. But unable to do it. Its leaving some nodes without traversing. Please help.

```
public void reverseOrderTr() {
    reverseOrderT(root);
}

private void reverseOrderT(BinaryTreeNode t) {
    if (t != null) {
        String v = t.nodeData;
        char tav = (Character.toUpperCase(v.charAt(0)));
        if (tav == 'A' ||
                tav == 'E' ||
                tav == 'I' ||
                tav == 'O' ||
                tav == 'U') {
            reverseOrderT(t.rightNode);
            System.out.print(t.nodeData + " ");
            reverseOrderT(t.leftNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only traversing subnodes of nodes with vowel-starting data.

Move the test deeper into the block, just around the `print` function.